# How to archive project with iOS 6.1 base SDK on Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I have Xcode5 and I added iOS 6.1 SDK to it.
In my project, I chose iOS 6.1 as the base SDK and also chose 6.1 as Deployment Target.
My aim is to archive the project to an .ipa with iOS 6.1 SDK and 6.1 deployment target settings.

I am trying to archive my project but I'm getting an error:

```
Apple Match-O Linker Error
ld: library not found for -lobjc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

How can I fix this error to make possible archive project on Xcode5 with iOS 6.1 SDK for the 6.1 deployment target?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We was initially doing something similar (with no issues however) but then realised that xibs we're being compiled against iOS 7 regardless so although the app was compiled against 6.1, there were top layout guide issues and UISegmentControls were iOS 7 styled... In the end we decided it was safer to just have a dmg of Xcode 4.6 and open that to archive for iOS 6 apps

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will install Xcode 4.6.3 and try it as you said.

Comment: Guys, the proposed by L14M333 solution worked for me. Still wondering how to do it with only one version of Xcode, with Xcode5. Any ideas?